# Ordenar resultados extraídos mediante Simple Html DOM

Tags: php, scraping, simple-html-dom

Estoy comenzando algo sencillo mediante Simple Html DOM para capturar algunos valores que necesito en ciertas páginas.

La página donde haré el raspado es esta: https://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/Leather_Helmet

Y mi código para raspar es este:

```
  <?php
    require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/Leather_Helmet');


// Comprar
echo "<br><b>Comprar a:</b><br>";
    foreach($html->find('div##item-trades-buyfrom td') as $val_buy){
        echo $val_buy->plaintext;
        echo "<br>";
    }

// Vender
echo "<br><b>Vender a:</b><br>";
    foreach($html->find('div##item-trades-sellto td') as $val_sell){
        echo $val_sell->plaintext;
        echo "<br>";
    }



?>

</body>

</html>
```

En cuanto a los valores, todos son correctos, es decir, mi código funciona.

El resultado que obtengo es este:

```
**Comprar a:**
Aldo
Venore
12
Azil
Darashia
12
Baltim
Svargrond*
12
Brengus
Port Hope
12
Cedrik
Liberty Bay
12
Coltrayne
Dawnport
12
Cornelia
Carlin
12
Dixi
Rookgaard
12
Esrik
Farmine
12
Flint
Rathleton
12
Gamel
Thais
12
Hardek
Thais*
12
Kroox
Kazordoon
12
Lee'Delle
Rookgaard
11
Memech
Ankrahmun
12
Morpel
Yalahar
12
Robert
Svargrond
12
Sam
Thais
12
Shanar
Ab'Dendriel
12
Turvy
Thais
12
Ulrik
Thais*
12
Willard
Edron
12
Yanni
Venore
12

**Vender a:**
Aldo
Venore
4
Azil
Darashia
4
Baltim
Svargrond*
4
Brengus
Port Hope
4
Cedrik
Liberty Bay
4
Cornelia
Carlin
4
Dixi
Rookgaard
3
Esrik
Farmine
4
Flint
Rathleton
4
Gamel
Thais
4
H.L.
Venore*
1
Hardek
Thais*
4
Kroox
Kazordoon
4
Lee'Delle
Rookgaard
3
Memech
Ankrahmun
4
Morpel
Yalahar
4
Raffael
Island of Destiny
4
Robert
Svargrond
4
Sam
Thais
4
Shanar
Ab'Dendriel
4
Turvy
Thais
4
Ulrik
Thais*
4
Willard
Edron
4
Yanni
Venore
4
```

Ahora viene el problema...

Mi problema radica en que quiero almacenar esos valores en arreglos individuales (no como objetos), para de ese modo manipular cada dato de forma individual. Al final de todo quiero llegar a este formato:

```
Comprar a:
//nombre + ciudad + valor
Aldo Venore 12
Azil Darashia 12
Baltim Svargrond* 12
...
...
Cedrik Liberty Bay 12
```

Y exactamente lo mismo para la parte de **Vender a**.

Quisiera raspar los valores y almacenarlos automáticamente uno por uno en arrays y que al final me muestre los valores concatenados de la forma `nombre + ciudad + valor`. Por ejemplo:

```
    $array = nombre('Aldo','Azil','Baltim');
    $array = ciudad('Venore','Darashia','Svargrond');
    $array = valor('12','12','12');

    echo array $nombre[0] + array $ciudad[0] + array $valor[0];
    echo array $nombre[1] + array $ciudad[1] + array $valor[1];
    echo array $nombre[2] + array $ciudad[2] + array $valor[2];

    //Aldo Venore 12
    //Azil Darashia 12
    //Baltim Svargrond 12
```

Al final de todo el proceso mi intención es almacenar esos valores en una base de datos para usarlos más adelante, por eso me urge que cada valor esté por separado.

En pocas palabras: raspar y obtener de la tabla lo siguiente: nombre, ciudad, valor y almacenar cada dato en un arreglo para ser usado mas adelante. Mostrar esos dato por pantalla.

Espero se entienda mi consulta, estaré pendiente para agregar detalles en caso de ser necesario. Gracias de antemano por ayudarme en esto. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si los datos vienen organizados siempre de tres en tres, puedes:

1. Dividir `$html->find('div##item-trades-buyfrom td')` en grupos de tres con [**`array_chunk()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php)
2. Iterar esos grupos de tres y meter cada valor por su índice en su respectivo array.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Arrays por separado
$mNames=array();
$mLastNames=array();
$mValues=array();

#Dividimos los datos en grupos de tres
$mChunks = array_chunk($html->find('div##item-trades-buyfrom td', 3);

#Recorremos los grupos
foreach ($mChunks as $chunk){
    $mNames[]=$chunk[0]->plaintext;
    $mLastNames[]=$chunk[1]->plaintext;
    $mValues[]=$chunk[2]->plaintext;
}

#Prueba de los resultados
var_dump($mNames);
var_dump($mLastNames);
var_dump($mValues);
```

**Salida:**

Nombres:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Aldo"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Aldo2"
}
```

Apellidos:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Venore"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Venore2"
}
```

Valores:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "13"
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Hice la prueba como indicas y me arroja este error:

_Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array_

Comment: @NickCam Al ver que leías esto `$html->find('div##item-trades-buyfrom td') as $val_buy` dentro de un `foreach` pensé que sería un array. ¿Podrías mostrar qué arroja un `var_dump($html->find('div##item-trades-buyfrom td') as $val_buy);` para ver qué es lo que hay ahí?